Extrusions Not Joining Up
My Ender 3 has printed (fairly) happily for several years, but now it has suddenly displayed a new problem. The brim prints PERFECTLY and stays stuck, but as the actual model layers off that, I can see that perimeter extrusions REMAIN SEPARATE from their horizontal neighbours (as though the extrusion was too thin, yet the filament push motor is clicking away). There is a very fine gap between extrusion 'lines' in every direction. I have tried changing the PLA reel, replaced the 0.4 brass nozzle, and recently replaced the bowen tube. I always print at 210deg with 0.15 layers. What am I suddenly doing wrong?

Please add photos to support your question!

I would if I could see how to. I think I may have found an answer - the same model printed perfectly later using a different reel of filament. I suspect therefore that the problem lies with the brand used and I have contacted the supplier (who is Chinese so I don't expect much of a response).

Did you measure the diameter of the filament with a caliper?
